# Exporting csv file from postgresql database server to local machine

Tags: sql, postgresql, export-to-csv

I'm trying to download the select output query as a csv file into my local machine, from the server where the database is stored. I tried using the `\copy` command :

```
\copy (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table) to 'C:\Folder\temp.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

It gives output `COPY 1` in the terminal, but doesn't generate any csv file in the location. Would really appreciate any help, thanks !

Comment: Could it be that you're closing the path with a ` instead of a single quote ' ?

Comment: Not sure if this is cut and paste error, but  `'C:\Folder\temp.csv`` should be `'C:\Folder\temp.csv'`.  This command(with ` changed to ') worked for me on a Linux machine, in that I got `COPY 1` and a `temp.csv` file was created.  Do you have correct permissions on that directory? Also try it with `'C:/Folder/temp.csv'`.

Comment: Really sorry, I typed it out wrong here and I've corrected it now. And no, when I use the path `C:/Folder/temp.csv` it says "No such file or directory".

Answer (score 1):

You're closing the file path with a **`** instead of with a **'**, so I guess there is a file somewhere with different name than the one you're expecting ;) Otherwise the command is just fine

```
\copy (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) TO 'C:\Folder\temp.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

Comment: Actually closing with a ` will get you a syntax error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: ...PY  ( SELECT COUNT ( * ) FROM animals ) TO STDOUT ,' HEADER;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I also think so, but since I do not have a windows machine to test exactly what happens, I assume the file is being created. In my linux environment I also get an error

Comment: @TonyStark do you get any result with this command: `\copy (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) TO STDOUT WITH HEADER CSV DELIMITER ',';`?

Comment: Yes, I get this : `COPY 1`. I'm running this on my company database server since I need to get data from there, is it possible that the server isn't allowing files to be downloaded.

Comment: @TonyStark did you set the output to `STDOUT` in my last command? It should display the content in the terminal ..

Comment: Another option would be to tell psql to do it for you: `psql -d db -c "COPY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) TO STDOUT WITH HEADER CSV DELIMITER ','" > C:\folder\file.csv`

Comment: Yeah, I get the total rows as the output, `10040`. Will try the psql command, thanks man.

Comment: @TonyStark does this command work on windows? `psql -d db -c "COPY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ','" > C:\folder\file.csv `

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me sadly @JimJones

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233450/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-tony-stark).